# Typescript :Property 'className' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am using draggable in my code like this:
First to create and append the element:

```
let myImg = document.createElement("img");
myImg.setAttribute('src', ...);
myImg.id = some_value;
myImg.className = "store_img";
myImg.draggable = true;

myImg.addEventListener('dragstart',function(event){
    event.dataTransfer?.setData("text", somedata);
    myImg.style.opacity = "0.5";

myImg.addEventListener('dragend',function(){
    mask.style.opacity = "1";
   
document.getElementById("myStorageDiv")?.appendChild(myImg);
```

After that, somewhere else I modify the "myStorageDiv" to allow accepting the draggable:

```
document.getElementById("myArea")?.addEventListener('dragenter', 
function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.dataTransfer?.getData("className") == "store_img"){
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}, false);
```

the last line tells me className not exist on 'EventTarget'. The reason I want to use it is I have two types of draggable, each one only allowed for one area, I want those areas to identify where the draggable comes from before making any changes, ex.'if(event.target.className == "StoreImg"){...}'. I also notice dataTransfer's data can only be used in Drop, so I can't pass the className for others like dropenter and dropleave. Is there any alternative ways for doing it? Thanks!

Comment: Which interface does variable `event` expected? If you're on VS Code you should be able to see it by hovering the variable with your mouse.

Comment: it says '(parameter) event: DragEvent'

Comment: But is the className a property of the HTML element or of the event? Because it seems to me that you want to edit the className of the img element.

Comment: The reason I did this is I saw sample codes on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drag_event, which doesn't work in my case. If we forget about this, is there another way to do that? Doesn't have to be className, anything that could seperate my draggables in different classes?

Comment: Does it not work to do `myImg.className = "StoreImg"` instead of `event.target.className = "StoreImg"`?

Comment: Yes it will work, but the problem is I don't know how to refer it outside, inside my DropEnter function, how do I make something similar to `if(event.target.className == "StoreImg"){then ...}` or saying what should replace the 'event.target.classname'.

Comment: Can you post a bigger chunk of your code? That would make it easier to understand the issue. Maybe you could write a minimal example illustrating the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Let's see if I understand your issue correctly, you want to change the class for `myImg` based on an event and also test which class does it currently have, right?

TypeScript aside, this should be easily achiavable, here's an example (try dragging the image):

```js
const myImg = document.querySelector("#my-img");

myImg.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {      
  if (myImg.className == "blue") {
    alert("Element was blue, I guess.");
  }
  
  myImg.className = "red";
})
```

```css
.blue {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  color: blue;
}

.red {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<img id="my-img" class="blue" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/95686594a8e10ec60422e9478e9d1785"></img>
```

Does that work for you or do you get some TypeScript error? If you do you can post it here and I'll try to help.

Comment: I have edited my question. So the problem is like this, I have two classes draggable D1 and D2, area A1 and A2, I want A1 only do something if D1 enters it, if D2 enters it should not do anything, same for D2 and A2. Is there anything I can put in IF LOOP to identify where the draggable comes from? Thanks